# When creating an instance from an api call, how to increment an attribute of another entity in dotnet ef?

Tags: c#, sql, .net, api, entity-framework

In an api I have built using dotnet 3.1, I have the Data access model for entity "Quotation" as follows.

```
public class QuotationDao : BaseEntity
    {
        public double Amount { get; set; }
        public DateTime FromDate { get; set; }
        public DateTime ToDate { get; set; }
        public string Status { get; set; }

        public Guid CustomerId { get; set; }
        public CustomerDao Customer { get; set; }
        
        public virtual ICollection<QuoteItemDao> Items { get; set; }
    }
```

When I create a new instance of the entity 'QuoteItem', I want to increase the 'amount' attribute of the 'Quotation' entity by 1. And update the database.

The implementation of the BaseController.cs is shown below.

```
public class BaseController<TDao, TCreateRq, TUpdateRq, TResponse> : ControllerBase
        where TDao : BaseEntity where TResponse : BaseResponse
    {
        private readonly IRepositoryWrapper _repositoryWrapper;
        private readonly IRepositoryBase<TDao> _repository;
        private readonly IMapper _mapper;

        public BaseController(IRepositoryWrapper repositoryWrapper, IRepositoryBase<TDao> repository, IMapper mapper)
        {
            _repositoryWrapper = repositoryWrapper;
            _repository = repository;
            _mapper = mapper;
        }

        [HttpGet]
        public virtual async Task<ActionResult<PagedResponse<TResponse>>> GetAll([FromQuery] StringQueryRequest request)
        {
            var paginationFilter = _mapper.Map<PaginationFilter>(request);
            var pagedResponse = await _repository.ToPagedList
                (_repository.FindAll(request.SearchString), paginationFilter);

            var mapPagination = pagedResponse.MapPagination<TResponse, TDao>(_mapper);
            return mapPagination.HandleToResponse();
        }

        [HttpGet("{id:guid}")]
        public virtual async Task<ActionResult<Response<TResponse>>> GetById(Guid id)
        {
            var result = await GetDtoById(id);

            return result.HandleGetToResponse();
        }

        [HttpPost]
        public virtual async Task<ActionResult<Response<TResponse>>> Create([FromBody] TCreateRq request)
        {
            var entity = _mapper.Map<TDao>(request);
            _repository.Create(entity);
            await _repositoryWrapper.SaveAsync();
            var baseResponse = _mapper.Map<TResponse>(entity);
            var result = new Result<TResponse>(baseResponse);

            return result.HandleToResponse();
        }

        [HttpPut("{id:guid}")]
        public virtual async Task<ActionResult<Response<TResponse>>> UpdateById([FromRoute] Guid id,
            [FromBody] TUpdateRq updateRq)
        {
            var getResult = await GetDtoById(id);
            if (getResult.IsNone)
            {
                return getResult.HandleGetToResponse();
            }

            var value = await _repository.FindById(id);
            //override the current DB objet from the values received from the request
            //Not replacing the full object from the requests as some fields may be missing from the update RQ model (eg user password)
            var entity = _mapper.Map(updateRq, value);
            _repository.Update(entity);
            await _repositoryWrapper.SaveAsync();
            var baseResponse = _mapper.Map<TResponse>(entity);
            var result = new Result<TResponse>(baseResponse);

            return result.HandleToResponse();
        }

        [HttpDelete("{id:guid}")]
        public virtual async Task<ActionResult<Response<TResponse>>> DeleteById([FromRoute] Guid id)
        {
            var getResult = await GetDtoById(id);
            if (getResult.IsNone)
            {
                return getResult.HandleGetToResponse();
            }

            var baseResponse = getResult.ValueUnsafe();
            var entity = _mapper.Map<TDao>(baseResponse);
            _repository.Delete(entity);
            await _repositoryWrapper.SaveAsync();
            var result = new Result<TResponse>(baseResponse);

            return result.HandleToResponse();
        }

        private async Task<Option<TResponse>> GetDtoById(Guid id)
        {
            var findById = await _repository.FindById(id);
            return _mapper.Map<TResponse>(findById);
        }
    }
```

I cant figure out a way to implement this and I'd be grateful if someone could give some help.

Comment: What type of ``TDao``?

Comment: I've edited the question with the full implementation of the BaseController.cs class. Please check it out

Comment: Can you clarify what it is you are trying to accomplish? You want amount to reflect the number of objects in the database or to add an incremented number to each object in the database?

Answer (score 0):

This is the problem with relying on a purely Generic approach. Generic implies that regardless of what you pass in, they can be treated within the scope of the Generic class as ***identical***. That said, as a base implementation, what you have isn't bad, but you are going to hit some limitations since a Generic implementation represents a "lowest common denominator" in terms of leveraging what EF can bring to the table.

Your issue can be addressed by structuring your controllers around aggregate roots and performing operations through those roots. The trouble you will find when working with related entities is that your controllers will need to know about these relationships in order to ensure required details are eager loaded to work with. You can leverage a Generic base class for controllers and repositories, but the actual controllers and repositories would be scoped around the aggregate root such as the Quotation. Adding quotation items would be done through its root (Quotation) rather than having something like a QuotationItemController and QuotationItemRepository. The goal of the QuotationController would be to support methods that can load a Quotation with it's respective items and have a method like AddQuotationItem. AddQuotationItem would then load the Quotation by ID, eager loading the items, validate the input for a QuotationItem, Create the QuotationItem, append it to the quote.Items, and increment the quote's Amount before saving the changes.

The key here would be to not think of fitting everything into a Generic pattern, but more-so leveraging a Generic if needed for elements of the controller or repositories etc. that are identical.

Some other tips: Which mapper are you using? If it is Automapper then consider using `ProjectTo<TDestination>(config)` rather than `Map<TDestination>()` when projecting to the view model. The benefit here is that the projection works across the `IQueryable` rather than introducing the overhead of fetching Entities and counting on related entities to be eager loaded or waking the performance troll that is lazy loading. This will be problematic with methods like `FindAll` if that is returning `IEnumerable<TEntity>` but if it is returning `IQueryable<TEntity>` then you should be set. Passing FindAll to something like ToPagedList won't save performance hits if FindAll is returning `IEnumerable`.  When converting back from a view model to a DTO, provided your entities are tracked you should avoid using `Update` and just use Automapper's
`mapper.Map(updateRq, value)` which will copy the values from source to destination. If Destination is a tracked entity, then just call `SaveChanges` and EF will build an appropriate UPDATE statement for just the values that changed if any values actually changed. (`Update` will generate an UPDATE statement for all values even if nothing actually changed.)

That `Update` pattern is more a case of using:

```
var dao = mapper.Map<TEntity>(dto);
context.Update(dao);
context.SaveChanges();
```

which I would never recommend using over:

```
var dao = context.Entities.Single(x => x.Id == dto.Id);
mapper.Map(dto, dao);
context.SaveChanges();
```

As the later pattern validates that the dto passed in has a corresponding entity, Automapper should be configured to only copy across allowed properties according to configured rules, then `SaveChanges` would produce an efficient UPDATE SQL statement only if anything actually changed.